# How to make a switch case statement for every element in an array in java?

Tags: android, for-loop, switch-statement, spinner, android-arrayadapter

so in short terms I have this arraylist that contains names of cities (New York, San Francisco, Seattle etc). And the user adds to that array, so for each user that array is going to be a different size and have different names. I'm trying to make a drop down menu spinner and for that I need to use a switch statement. So, I'm not sure how to loop through the arraylist and make a case statement for every element of the array? Can someone help with this?

cheers~

```
                        dropDownspinner.setAdapter(citySpinner);
                        dropDownspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
                            {
                                switch (i)
                                {
                                    //So i'm wondering how I can use a for loop and make a case for every element in an array.
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: "and for that I need to use a switch statement": how did you get this idea?

Comment: @Henry In every example, I have ever seen when making a drop down menu with a spinner in android that takes in an array adapter, a switch statement is always used to make every item in the drop down spinner. I'm not sure any other way to implement it. But i still want to know if you can make a case statement for every element in an arrayList

Comment: getView(int position){ String name = array.get(position)}.

Comment: @TheQ .Plz post your example.

Comment: @tinysunlight I added what I was trying to do but I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Show me what do you want to do  when you just has 3 place  : place A ,place b, place c.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the data of the cities for each user in hashmap where the key would be username and value would be list of cities for each user?

For example if you have the list of cities for user1 as listOfUser1Cities which is of type List, then you could do:

```
Map<String, List<String>> userCities = new HashMap();
userCities.put("user1", listOfUser1Cities);
```

and to retrieve user1 data, of course you could just do:

```
userCities.get("user1");
```

to get the cities for that user. No switch-case would be required in this way.

Comment: I put some code in. I'm not sure if your method would work. Because I have to work with each position thats selected in OnItemSelected() method,

Answer (score 0):

```
 dropDownspinner.setAdapter(citySpinner);
                dropDownspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
                    {
                       Log.e("selected:",list.get(i))
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
```